# DoubleClick Selected Row in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Right now when I Double Click on a single row of populated data in datagrid1, it populates 2 rows of data in datagrid 2. How do I get it to just populate the information from just one single row when it is clicked on?

When a button is clicked it pulls information from specified tables and populates information into datagrid 1. When  person double clicks on a single row in datagrid 1 it will display separate information from a different table into datagrid 2. The code for Xaml and Code Behind is below:

```
<DataGrid Height="386" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" Width="832" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataBinding}" Name="datagrid1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" Background="White" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" ColumnWidth="110">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>



 private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        conConnect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GERRY;Initial Catalog=ToyDB;Integrated Security=True");

        dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ToyInfo", conConnect);
        DS = new DataSet();

        dAdapter.Fill(DS, "MyDataBinding");

        datagrid2.DataContext = DS;

        dAdapter.Dispose();
        conConnect.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Actually, your code populates datagrid2 with all records from the ToyInfo table. What do you really try to achieve? Please be more specific about your problem, and how the ToyInfo table is populated or how it should be queried.

Comment: The ToyInfo table is populated with data by me manually inserting the information into the columns.

Comment: So, datagrid2 is showing all records you did put manually into ToyInfo. Still, i have no clue about what you really try to achieve...

Comment: The ToyInfo table is populated with data by me manually inserting the information into the columns. 1)DataGrid 1 is populated with information I have entered into the columns. Then gets displayed into the datagrid when the end user clicks a button. 2) The ToyInfo table includes separate and additional information that I do not include into DataGrid 1. That information is being displayed into DataGrid 2. 3) When the user clicks on a Specific Row in DataGrid 1 it queries the ToyInfo Table for that associated row in datagrid 1. Then displays the information into DataGrid 2.

Comment: You say "it queries the ToyInfo Table for that associated row in datagrid 1", but your code doesn't do it. It does "SELECT * FROM ToyInfo". You should have something like a WHERE clause in your SQL statement, selecting a particular record based on some data from the selection in datagrid1.

Comment: Ok, I got that part that is not hard to do but I need to expand the WHERE clause to search across all the fields in the ToyInfo Table. So how do I got about doing that?

Comment: I suggest to learn the basics of SQL, especially regarding [simple WHERE clauses](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sql+tutorial+where+clause).

Comment: Well this conversation was about as helpful as a heart attack, I thought people was suppose to help. So far I have received no helpful information at all just a suggestion on something that I have already been doing. Why post code to just get verbal suggestions instead of actually posting some code that might be helpful. Guess I should just rely on the MSDN forums where people actually help.